# How to get value to work in php and html tag?

Tags: php, html

The first file (which is html) has two inputs and the second file (php) is the form to display the data when submitted. I want the php file to print whatever message is typed into the input and submitted.

html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome_get.php file:

```
<html>
<body>
    Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"];?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it is probably very simple but for some reason, whenever I type something into the input and submit, it doesn't display the values I inputted. It just displays only the message in the php file:

```
Welcome
Your email address is:
```

Comment: can you see the values in url ?

Comment: If the PHP file is accessable and has the correct name it is probably something your server does with the $_SERVER variable. You don't see anything because your error reporting is turned off. It is probably throwing a notice error. Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on top of your PHP file (within the `<?php` tag and `var_dump($_SERVER);` after that.

Comment: try var_dump($_GET); what it display?

Comment: are they on the same folder on your document? and check the url, like: `http://localhost/yourfolder/welcome_get.php?name=test&email=test` something like that

Comment: @M.chaudhry Yes I can.

Comment: Try setting your form's action to post and see what happens...I have several pages that open via form action with method="post"...then I $_GET the vars on the newly opened page...pages do not open properly ($_GET doesn't retrieve vars) with method="get"...couldn't hurt to try, right? One difference though...my pages open with input type="image" instead of input type="submit"

Comment: bring them up in one page for debugging let see your code works or not if yes then check ur page's locations

Comment: I have tried all of these ways and still get no output. @M.chaudhry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: did you try this whole code on one page with action=""?

Comment: @M.chaudhry I did what you said and it still doesn't come up with the output although is still appears in the URL.

Comment: it is strange can you post your more code or what server you are using

Answer (score 0):

Use isset to check the variables exist before you use them. i.e.

```
<html>
<body>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['name'])){
            echo 'Welcome '. $_GET["name"] .'<br>';
        }

        if(isset($_GET['email'])){
            echo 'Your email address is: '. $_GET["email"] .'<br>';
        }        
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

additionally, it's worth ensuring you have all errors displayed by putting this at the top of your file:

```
<?php
   display_errors(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
?>
```

finally, check you're php install is working correctly, by creating a new file (phpinfo.php) with the following contents:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

open this in the browser, and check you get the about php page.